# Node.js execSync returning undefined but console.log works

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen a similar question once, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. I have a pretty simple program below that should wrap the exec function and return the result. However all it returns is undefined. Here's the function:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

quickexec = function(command) {
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(error) {
            return error;
        } else {
            return stdout;
        }
    });
};
```

I call it like this `console.log(quickexec('echo -n $USER'));` and I get undefined everytime. However if I change the return in my function to a console.log it works. I thought that it was an async problem which is why I started using `execSync`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: *"I thought that it was an async problem"* it is. Why do you think you have to pass a callback in the first place? Also, `quickexec` doesn't contain a `return` statement. What solution are you looking for? Technically it's a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Answer (score 0):

`quickexec()` does not actually return anything.  The `return` inside it are in the async callback which happens long after `quickexec()` has already returned.  You can't synchronously return an asynchronous result.  This is a common issue when learning how to do proper asynchronous programming in node.js.

If you need a synchronous result, you can use [`execsync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options), but usually the best design is to use the asynchronous result in the callback.

```
var quickexec = function(command, callback) {
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            callback(null, stdout);
        }
    });
};

quickexec('echo -n $USER', function(err, result) {
    // use the result here in the callback
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```